# Unfortunate non-responsive HR menu on website

Tags: css

I have the following website which I've been building as part of my graduate work (http://www.ecu.edu/english/tpc/tpcintern/) and it seems to be working pretty well except that the top-most navigation section (the menu bar and the small icons which represent social networks). The CSS used is below:

```
#navigation {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 font-style: normal;
 float: left;
 margin: .5em 0 0 .5em;
 width: 70%;
 height: 2em;
 position: relative;
 padding: .5em 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1em;
 background-color: #592a8a;
}

#navigation ul {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

#navigation li {
 font-weight: bold;
 display: inline;
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 11em;
 height: 2em;
 text-align: center;
 padding: .5em 0 0 0;
}

#navigation li:first-child {
 border-left: 0;
}

#navigation li:last-child {
 border-right: 0;
}

#navigation li a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 border: 0;
 text-decoration: underline;
}


#social ul {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 width: 100%;
}

#social li {
 position: relative;
 top: -1.5em;
 left: 1em;
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 4em;
 height: 3em;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 2em 1em 0 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#social li:first-child {
 border-left: 0;
}

#social li:last-child {
 border-right: 0;
}
```

The rest of the site seems to be pretty fluid but I can't seem to figure out the menu bar part. It just breaks when the screen size gets too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the height from the #navigation element, the text will no longer be hidden when you minimize the browser.

To make changes to the site based on the width of the browser use a media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   #social_media {
      display:none;
   }
}
```

In this example at a resolution of below 480px the #social_media element will disappear.

Comment: That does work pretty well. Is there any way that I can eliminate the menu marked as #Social when the browser gets smaller? Also, is there any way that I can make the menu thinner that won't also break the layout?

Comment: Yeah there is.  The media query, I edited my answer to show usage.  You can also use this method to change around properties for the menu so it looks cleaner when the user begins minimizing.